# Returning data from server-side user control components in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an aspx/WebForms page that includes a user control.  This user control contains, among other things, a Repeater that forms a UI for a user to input a variety of things.  The three most notable things in this repeater are a CheckBox, a DropDownList, and a TextBox.  There are an arbitrary number of lines in the repeater - it could be 0, could be 15.  Depends on the user.

I am able to retrieve data from my database and bind the data to the Repeater just fine.  The user control functions as it should during the main interaction time.

The problem arises when it comes time to recover the data the user has now edited.  Whether I use a component inside the user control or in the user control's parent page to cause a postback, the first whiff I get of the user control (in the parent page's `OnInit`) has re-created the user control and obliterated the data the user has input.  I have tried everything I can think of to get at the post back data, but it all turns out the same - by the time the WebForms give me any visibility to the data, it's gone.

How can I retrieve the modified data from the user control, without losing it to the parent page's templating system's overwrite?

Comment: The way I do this is to allow the client-side changes, and instead of postbacks, use AJAX to update your database. That way when the page does reload/postback, the data it loads is the updated data they have changed. PS. Also [UpdatePanels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx)

Comment: Normal case, any data you bind inside a repeater which is inside a user control should not go away on a postback. Are you sure you are checking for `Page.IsPostback` and then binding the repeater if its not `true` from within your usercontrol code?

Comment: @deostll Yes, I am checking that, but the problem is the data is GONE by the time I get visibility to the control.  By the time I get a glance at what's going on, ASP.NET's templating system has recreated the control and obliterated what I had data bound there.  This happens prior to `OnInit`, `OnLoad`, it happens prior to everything.  Whether or not it's a postback is immaterial.